# Would this question from the Freelancing stack be appropriate?

Tags: discussion, on-topic-definition

I posted the question below at the Freelancing stack

https://freelancing.stackexchange.com/questions/10215/dealing-with-a-startup-how-common-is-commercial-credit-vs-equity

But it is a pretty low traffic corner of the site, and seems to be visited mostly by people doing short runs at Upwork etc, which isn't really the situation in this question.

Would cross-posting this be OT?

Thanks

Comment: Probably not, but when you start doing exotic and wonderful things with startups, they usually end up draining your wallet

Comment: We used to have a Startups site that [closed for inactivity](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214315/what-happened-to-startups-se). That particular question reads like more of a [money.se] topic almost. I guess it's not explicitly off-topic here though I'm not sure it's something this community can effectively answer.

Comment: @Lilienthal, thanks for that first link... points to brightjourney.com, found many startup related discussions to do with equity and deferred compensation, although is less active now than early 2010s... Kilisi - yep that's my concern. There are tax issues too in the US

Answer (score 1):

The topic: Dealing with a startup, how common is commercial credit (vs equity)?

would get a lot of close votes on Personal Finance and Money. The focus of the site is personal finance with a little but of small business thrown in. This question would be beyond the score of the site.

I don't think it is a good match for the workplace, because the question isn't about navigating the workplace, it is about corporate finance.